# Load url with custom schema in webview

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I have a login page that returns a redirect URL in the form of `myschema://`.
It was originally intended to be used in Safari to redirect the user back to the application after successfully login.
Now I would like to use it with a modal webview instead, but I get an error on the redirect as the webview is not able to handle the URL.
Is there any setting or any workaround that I could use to fix the issue?
I am listening for the `load` event of the webview, but as I got the error, it is never fired.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `beforeload` event instead. This will get you the URL before it (fails to) load the url, allowing you do whatever you want with it.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.WebView-event-beforeload

Comment: I already tried this solution, but the redirection doesn't fire the `beforeload` event.

Comment: Mmm, that's unfortunate. Could you file a bug report for that on jira.appcelerator.org so I can back that up?